# Pandas reading a string from an API and creating and appending to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am iterating through a dataset to get a registration number and applying that to an API call to get additional information and below is the output I receive. How would I create a dataframe from this in pandas and append for additional calls? I have tried reading as csv, dict etc. I have used io.StringIO which stops it erroring but doesn't put it in a data frame correctly.

> {"registrationNumber":"LD2A","co2Emissions":10,"engineCapacity":297,"markedForExport":false,"fuelType":"DIESEL","motStatus":"Valid","colour":"SILVER"}

What is the best course of action to get this into a dataframe and then append for additional API calls?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `df = pd.Series({"registrationNumber":"LD2A","co2Emissions":10,"engineCapacity":297,"markedForExport":False,"fuelType":"DIESEL","motStatus":"Valid","colour":"SILVER"}).to_frame().T`  ?     Anyway, you have to determine whether `false` is a string or Boolean.  Change it to appropriate type first

Comment: I can see that works as is. When I run it through using the API function it puts everything into one column. Is this due to the false not being correctly defined but I would have thought I would have gotten an error? For the analysis I am doing its irrelevant ifs its a Boolean or string. Would i use df = pd.Series(df, dtype={"markedForExport": str}).to_frame().T

Comment: Thank you @SeaBean. I changed the response to JSON instead of text and your code worked perfectly. Cheers

Comment: That's great!  If you don't mind, I can still post my suggestion above as an answer for you to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a valid JSON file and fixed the issue of invalid input `false` which is neither a string nor a Boolean, you can use the following command to construct the dataframe:

```
j = {"registrationNumber":"LD2A","co2Emissions":10,"engineCapacity":297,"markedForExport": False,"fuelType":"DIESEL","motStatus":"Valid","colour":"SILVER"}

df = pd.Series(j).to_frame().T




print(df)

  registrationNumber co2Emissions engineCapacity markedForExport fuelType motStatus  colour
0               LD2A           10            297           False   DIESEL     Valid  SILVER
```